# Discord.py: Can't get mentioned user's information from DM

Tags: python, discord.py

I am attempting to get a mentioned user (other than those involved in the DM conversation). I've written this so far, it works if used in the channel, however doesn't work when used in a DM:

```
if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
    user = message.server.get_member_named(message.content.split()[1])
    await client.send_message(user, "you got message!")
```

The above always returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_member_named'` if used whilst in a DM.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private channels don't have a server.  Instead, you can loop through all the servers your bot is in and check each of them (this is how the `User` converter works when in a private channel)

```
result = None
for server in client.servers:
    result = server.get_member_named(name)
    if result:
        break
if result:
    # User found
else:
    # User not found
```